# How to schedule a piece of code to execute in the next runloop in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

There is no `[NSRunLoop -performSelector:target:argument:order:modes:]` in Swift currently. So does the `[NSObject -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`. How can I schedule a piece of code to execute in the next runloop in Swift?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to do so. Just enqueue a block based operation on the main queue with `OperationQueue`(`NSOperationQueue` in Cocoa).

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in
    // Do your things
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 and 4:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    // ...
}
```

In Swift version below 3:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Comment: This call basically means insert this block of code after current main queue's job